# How to get access to hosted mail inbox in cpanel

Tags: email, hosted

i opened an email from my hosted site cpanel "support@example.com" but i don't know how to see the mails sent to me.please help me out

Any advice is highly welcome

Answer (score 0):

Click on the:

> webmail>Go to Secure Webmail Login

and now select one of the services to access your inbox.